# Oracle Multi Row Update using Subquery

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

I am trying to "shuffle" last_names values in the names table. I am wanting to use a sub-select query that randomizes the order of the names and updates them accordingly. I wanting to do this for obfuscation reasons but want it to still look like a real data set.

The statement below returns a "ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row"

How can I make this work?

```
UPDATE schema.names set last_name = (
      SELECT * 
        FROM (
         SELECT last_name
         FROM schema.names
         ORDER BY DBMS_RANDOM.RANDOM))
```

Comment: Add `where rownum = 1` to the outer `SELECT`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff this will set all lastnames to one random lastname though right? I want all the names to be shuffled around but unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: the following PL/SQL block uses the query from Gordon's answer to drive a loop.

Setup:

```
create table demo
( name_original varchar2(10)
, name_new      varchar2(10) );

-- Two columns initially the same so we can check the results:
insert into demo
select column_value, column_value
from table(sys.dbms_debug_vc2coll('Jim','James','Joe','Jenny','Jane','Jacky'));
```

Code:

```
begin
    for r in (
        select n.rowid as rwd
             , n.name_original
             , n2.name_new as name_shuffled
        from   ( select n.*, row_number() over(order by dbms_random.value) as seqnum
                 from   demo n ) n
               join  
               ( select n.*, row_number() over(order by dbms_random.value) as seqnum
                 from   demo n ) n2
               on n.seqnum = n2.seqnum
    )
    loop
        update demo set name_new = r.name_shuffled
        where  rowid = r.rwd;
    end loop;
end;
```

My original answer is below, not especially helpful to the OP but I thought it was technically interesting anyway:

---

The optimiser realises that an uncorrelated single-row subquery only needs to be executed once, so you get one value looked up and applied to all rows. Possibly there is a hint that prevents this but I couldn't find one from a quick look (`no_merge`, `no_unnest` and `rule` had no effect).

The following worked (Oracle 12.1) but only by imposing an additional rule that old and new names had to be different, making it a correlated subquery which the optimiser has to evaluate for each row. (It also generates duplicates, because each random lookup is independent, so it may be no use to you.)

```
update demo d set name_new =
       ( select name_new
         from   demo d2
         where  d2.name_new <> d.name_new
         order by dbms_random.random
         fetch first row only );

select * from demo;

NAME_ORIGINAL NAME_NEW
------------- ----------
Jim           Jenny
James         Jane
Joe           Jacky
Jenny         Jane
Jane          Jacky
Jacky         Jim
```

At the risk of drifting off-topic, notice how adding the predicate `where  d2.name_new <> d.name_new` changes the execution plan from this:

```
Plan hash value: 1813657616

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                    | Name | Starts | E-Rows | A-Rows |   A-Time   | Buffers |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | UPDATE STATEMENT             |      |      1 |        |      0 |00:00:00.01 |      27 |
|   1 |  UPDATE                      | DEMO |      1 |        |      0 |00:00:00.01 |      27 |
|   2 |   TABLE ACCESS STORAGE FULL  | DEMO |      1 |     82 |      6 |00:00:00.01 |       7 |
|*  3 |   VIEW                       |      |      1 |      1 |      1 |00:00:00.01 |       7 |
|*  4 |    WINDOW SORT PUSHED RANK   |      |      1 |     82 |      1 |00:00:00.01 |       7 |
|   5 |     TABLE ACCESS STORAGE FULL| DEMO |      1 |     82 |      6 |00:00:00.01 |       7 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------
   3 - filter("from$_subquery$_003"."rowlimit_$$_rownumber"<=1)
   4 - filter(ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY "DBMS_RANDOM"."RANDOM"())<=1)
```

to this:

```
Plan hash value: 1813657616
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                    | Name | Starts | E-Rows | A-Rows |   A-Time   | Buffers |  OMem |  1Mem | Used-Mem |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | UPDATE STATEMENT             |      |      1 |        |      0 |00:00:00.01 |      62 |       |       |          |
|   1 |  UPDATE                      | DEMO |      1 |        |      0 |00:00:00.01 |      62 |       |       |          |
|   2 |   TABLE ACCESS STORAGE FULL  | DEMO |      1 |     82 |      6 |00:00:00.01 |       7 |  1025K|  1025K|          |
|*  3 |   VIEW                       |      |      6 |      1 |      6 |00:00:00.01 |      42 |       |       |          |
|*  4 |    WINDOW SORT PUSHED RANK   |      |      6 |      4 |      6 |00:00:00.01 |      42 |  2048 |  2048 | 2048  (0)|
|*  5 |     TABLE ACCESS STORAGE FULL| DEMO |      6 |      4 |     30 |00:00:00.01 |      42 |  1025K|  1025K|          |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------
   3 - filter("from$_subquery$_003"."rowlimit_$$_rownumber"<=1)
   4 - filter(ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY "DBMS_RANDOM"."RANDOM"())<=1)
   5 - filter("D2"."NAME_NEW"<>:B1)
```

which is a neat example of the same execution plan (Plan hash value 1813657616) doing two rather different things, if ever you want one of those.

(If there is a hint that does the same thing, it would make a neat example of a hint changing the results.)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a query that shuffles the names:

```
select n.*, n2.name as new_name
from (select n.*, row_number() over (order by dbms_random.random) as seqnum
      from schema.names n
     ) n join
     (select n.*, row_number() over (order by dbms_random.random) as seqnum
      from schema.names n
     ) n2 
     on n.seqnum = n2.seqnum;
```

You can incorporate this into a `merge`, assuming you have a primary key:

```
merge into schema.names n
    using (select n.*, n2.name as new_name
           from (select n.*, row_number() over (order by dbms_random.random) as seqnum
                 from schema.names n
                ) n join
                (select n.*, row_number() over (order by dbms_random.random) as seqnum
                 from schema.names n
                ) n2 
                on n.seqnum = n2.seqnum
          ) nn
    on n.? = nn.?
when matched then update
    set n.name = nn.new_name;
```

Comment: Not working for the query that shuffles names, "ORA-24804: Lob read/write functions called while another OCI LOB read/write streaming is in progress" Also needs to be DBMS_RANDOM.RANDOM instead of dbs.random.