# plsql - permutation update

Tags: oracle, sql-update, permutation

I'd like to anonymise names in a large table. For this I'd like to permute this names. How can I do this?

I tried the following

```
update (
select t.id, t.name, t.nr,
       r.id, r.name, r.nr
from (select id, name, rownum nr from person) T
     inner join (select id, name, rownum nr from (select id, name from person order by DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE)) R
     on T.nr = R.nr
) set t.name = r.name;
```

The select part works fine but not the update part.

Any idea?

Comment: Seems similar to this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/49634350/230471

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the way

```
update  person T
set name = (select rn.name
              from (select id, name, rownum nr from person) ref
                   inner join (select id, name, rownum nr from (select id, name from person order by DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE)) rn
                   on ref.nr = rn.nr
              where T.id=ref.id);
```

but there is a performance issue on large table

and here is the version with mutch better performances

```
merge into person A
using (select rn.name from (select id, name, rownum nr from person) ref
                           inner join (select id, name, rownum nr from (select id, name from person order by DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE)) rn
                           on ref.nr = rn.nr) B
on A.id = B.id
when matched then
update set a.name = B.name;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE in combination with rownum for this AND you want to update the IDs *in situ*, then you could use MERGE eg (Oracle 12c):

Setup

```
create table person 
as
select 1 id, 'name1' name from dual union all
select 2 , 'name2' from dual union all
select 3 , 'name3' from dual union all
select 4 , 'name4' from dual union all
select 5 , 'name5' from dual ;

SQL> select * from person;

        ID NAME 
---------- -----
         1 name1
         2 name2
         3 name3
         4 name4
         5 name5
```

MERGE

```
merge into person P
  using (    
     select id, name, rownum rn 
     from (
        select id, name 
        from person 
        order by DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE )
     ) R on ( P.id = R.rn )
  when matched then 
    update
    set P.name = R.name 
;

-- result
SQL> select * from person;

        ID NAME 
---------- -----
         1 name3
         2 name2
         3 name4
         4 name1
         5 name5
```

**Alternative**

It seems that you want to keep the names in clear text.  If this is the case, you could just randomise the IDs.  In the following example, the standard_hash() function has been used.

```
-- using the same PERSON table before ...

create table sha1
as
select 
  standard_hash( id )  as id
, name                 as name
from person ;

SQL> select * from sha1 order by id;
ID                                       NAME 
---------------------------------------- -----
1BBCAEE2AEA36F9E06501F5E7E85BF444D11A0C4 name4
B176DB7FBE17DDD94779DFAD1065D48D698082F1 name5
D0E90FA40F7B85F59C32F36D3FDB8BED9106DD14 name3
D961F70D39EE00CF78D4D476B80EF3AD5ABE128C name1
E39323970701D93598FC1D357F4BF04578CE3242 name2
```

You could dbms_random.value here, too - instead of standard_hash().  However, standard_hash() uses SHA1 by default, which has been designed to create unique checksums ie if your IDs are unique, the resulting SHA1 hash should be unique (commenters: I know that SHA1 collisions have been discovered).

Also, you are not destroying your original table (you can drop it later, if need be),  and the code is easier to understand than the MERGE code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but the first solution doesn-t work since P.id  doesn't match R.rn. The id are greater thant the rownum. It should be P.rownum = R.rownum.

For the second solution it doesn't work neither in my case since the id is used elsewhere

Comment: As for the second approach: you mean that the table containing the names does NOT have an ID column?

Comment: No the id is used for foreign keys and I don't want to change it in hundreds of tables